# spark read parquet vs pandas read parquet

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks, parquet

I just wanted to understand the difference between spark and pandas read parquet files command.

I have some data stored in my DBFS and I am using below commands to successfully read that data into my databricks instance:

```
d1 = spark.read.parquet('/user/hive/xyz/abc.db/test_file') --> this works for spark read
d2 = pd.read_parquet('/dbfs/user/hive/xyz/abc.db/test_file') --> this works for pandas read
```

I want to understand why I have to add the `"/dbfs"` at the start to be able to read the file using pandas. If I use the same path as `‘/user/hive/xyz/abc.db/test_file'` I get below error:

`Path does not exist: dbfs:/dbfs/user/hive//xyz/abc.db/test_file`

I am able to read file using both commands. I just want to understand why I need to change the path when I am using pandas parquet read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dbfs` is so-called DBFS fuse that exposes the DBFS to the programs that rely on the local file APIs (`open`, ... in Python, etc.).

By default, when you use Spark commands, then `dbfs:` scheme is default, so your path `/user/hive/xyz/abc.db/test_file` is actually: `dbfs:/user/hive/xyz/abc.db/test_file`.

Databricks documentation has a [good table](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html#understand-default-locations-with-examples) that describes differences between different file schemas, etc.